# Avoid having to update all rowIndexes every time I insert a new row in the middle of a GridPane?

Tags: javafx

If I have lots of rows and I feel like inserting a new one at the top (or at any other position) I then have to go and manually increment the GridPane.rowIndex field, which gets tiresome quite easily.

Is there any symbol I can put instead of the hardcoded numbers to make FXML understand that they're just a sequence?

```
...
<!-- inserting anything here will make me have to pudate the rowIndex of all
<!-- rows below it. quite tiresome?
<Text text="Trade ID:" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" />
<TextField fx:id="tradeIdField" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" editable="false" />
...
```

Thanks

Comment: No. Maybe you could use the `initialize`  method of a controller though to set those static properties by looping though the child list of the grid.  This would require a certain pattern you could exploit...

Comment: Argh... Does making these kinds of changes through the Scene Builder help me in any way?

Comment: It's drag and drop with [`SceneBuilder`](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

Comment: I have never tried it, but maybe try playing around with constant values, defines, references and bindings, as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html    I'm thinking something like `GridPane.rowIndex="${someConstant + 1}"` ... I have no idea if this will work....

Comment: Scene Builder will let you do this: it adds "handles" for each row and column which you can select, then right-click and do "add row above" etc.